# search result xml to list view?

Tags: list-view, xslt, search-results, xslt-list-view-web-part

is there an option how to render the search results xml like list view look&feel? For example I would like to configure that ok, this column should be rendered like a linktitle field type with all the fancy drop-down menu etc. ... where to start? Is this solvable with object model on server side or only with xslts ? Any hints? I will implement clicks on the backend side probably with post-back or mayby some ajax. For me most important part is the look&feel.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Creating something that looks like the LinkTitle field with the ECB (EditControlBlock) is "just" a matter of creating similar HTML and can be done purely in XSLT.

Getting the Standard ECB menu items security trimmed for a single list is doable, but requires code (server or client side).

Getting custom ECB menu items (Delegate controls) for a single list is very hard and requires server side code.

Getting a fully functional ECB menu for search results across lists/sites/site collections will be extremely hard to do efficiently and requires server side code.

Comment: yes, the requirement of the same look&feel is mandatory. i know it sounds crazy but ... i would probably go with rendering everything on the server-side without xslt to make my life easier however I am still not 100% sure if this is doable at all...

Answer (score -1):

I found that using SharePoint 2010 designer to customize resulting could ease the job.

Basically, you would have to make sure you have added all the columns already into the Core Search Results XML, and than use this to collect the full XML output by the web part

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xmp><xsl:copy-of select="*"/></xmp>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This could then be used a Data source for a Data View web part as described here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/tariq.younas/moss-2007-search-customization-using-sharepoint-designer/